# Cannot get rows filtered by group rows in sql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a table where there is a start date and end date these rows are group by unique id for example row id 4,5 have group_identify_id 5700045 and row id 1,2,3 have group_identify_id 5700044.I have to select only those group where all the rows of group have start column greater than current date. For eg. if current date is 15 then 5700045 should not be shown in result.

```
id                start                       end        group_identify_id

1          2019-07-18 07:15:00  2019-07-18 08:15:00          5700044
2          2019-07-16 07:15:00  2019-07-16 08:15:00          5700044
3          2019-07-17 07:15:00  2019-07-17 08:15:00          5700044
4          2019-07-15 07:15:00  2019-07-15 08:15:00          5700045
5          2019-07-14 07:15:00  2019-07-14 08:15:00          5700045
```

result should be something like this:

> result:

```
1          2019-07-18 07:15:00  2019-07-18 08:15:00          5700044
2          2019-07-16 07:15:00  2019-07-16 08:15:00          5700044
3          2019-07-17 07:15:00  2019-07-17 08:15:00          5700044
```

I was trying something like this:

```
$results =  $this->db->where('where('DATE(start) >=',$currentDate)->get('schedule_diary')->result();
```

but it matched the whole rows not group of rows.

Comment: What is value of `$currentDate`?

Comment: this variable contains todays date

Comment: I'm interested in, what is format of `$currentDate`.. is it comparable?

Comment: format of date 2019-07-15 12:14:50

Comment: @user3653474 Try removing time from $currentDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this raw query or convert it into the codeignieter format

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE DATE(START) > "$currentDate" AND group_identify_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct group_identify_id FROM test_1 WHERE DATE(START) <= "$currentDate")
```

It will work perfectly.

Working screenshot..

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE DATE(START) > date("2019-07-14") AND group_identify_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct group_identify_id FROM schedule_diary WHERE DATE(START) <= date("2019-07-14"))
```

[image]

Comment: @thanks I tried this query but it is not returning any results : $result=$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(START) > "$currentDate" AND group_unique_key NOT IN (SELECT distinct group_unique_key FROM table_name WHERE DATE(START) <= "$currentDate")')->result();

Comment: @user3653474 in which format you're passing the date.. use Y-m-d format or try this query.. SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE DATE(START) > date("$currentDate") AND group_identify_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct group_identify_id FROM test_1 WHERE DATE(START) <= date("$currentDate"))

Comment: @user3653474 Edited my question try to run that query.. don't pass the date parameter for testing..

Comment: Thanks it is working one thing more i want to clear if i have to use one more condition such as start time and end time. Every time i have to use the opposite condition of main query inside the sub query. For eg. AND (TIME(start) BETWEEN time("'.$start_time.'") AND time("'.$end_time.'") so inside the subquery we will have to use NOT BETWEEN.

Comment: Between is shorthand for >= and <=. So you can use these operator according to your requirement.

Comment: As you have used DATE(START) > date("2019-07-14")  in the outer query and in subquery it is the opposite condition DATE(START) <= date("2019-07-14") so for time i have to use the same concept sub query will contain condition opposite to outer query condition.

Comment: you can check the date and time together.. if you check the time in and condition like date < 2019-07- 14 and time > 10:00 and time < 12:00 then it will only check for 2 hours and date less than 2019-07-14. If you want to do like this then... use this query.. SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE DATE(START) > date("2019-07-14") AND TIME(start) BETWEEN time("00:00") AND time("12:00")  AND group_identify_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct group_identify_id FROM schedule_diary WHERE DATE(START) <= date("2019-07-14") AND TIME(start) <= time("00:00") and TIME(start) >= time("12:00"))

Answer (score 1):

Below is the raw query that would give you the required Result.

```
SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE group_identify_id NON IN ( SELECT group_identify_id FROM schedule_diary WHERE start  <= $currentDate) );
```

You need to convert this query into CodeIgniter Framework or you can also use $this->db->query('RawQueryHere')

Comment: $result=$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE(START) > "$currentDate" AND group_unique_key NOT IN (SELECT distinct group_unique_key FROM table_name WHERE DATE(START) <= "$currentDate")')->result();

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE
You could test with something like that **if you have values null in group_identify_id**:

```
  /*Firstly, you should to select a set of rows whiches not in date*/
    $this->db->where('t1.group_identify_id = schedule_diary.group_identify_id');
    $this->db->where('DATE(t1.start) <= GETDATE()');
    $subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select('schedule_diary as t1', TRUE);

  /*For last, you select all rows not exists in the subquery set.*/
    $this->db->where("not exists ($subquery)");
    $query = $this->db->get('schedule_diary');

    if($query){
      return $query->result_array();
    }
```

I think is right code for you!

Comment: Thanks nut it is not returning any row, i have some values are null in group_identify_id in my database.

Comment: Ok. Test now with NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I tried this query but it is not returning any result if i remove where condition then it print the result

Comment: Change CAST(t1.start as DATE) instead of DATE(t1.start). Notice to you that GETDATE function is today. Have you got rows for today?
I am testing in my computer and it is working in SQL server.

Comment: Or directly testing with this query:
```
SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM schedule_diary as t1 WHERE t1.group_identify_id = Test.group_identify_id and CAST(t1.start as DATE) <= '2019-07-15' ) 
´´´

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think, this `where` is odd there:

```
$results =  $this->db->where('where('DATE(start) >=',$currentDate)->get('schedule_diary')->result();
```

Try to remove it in your query:

```
$results =  $this->db->where('DATE(start) >=',$currentDate)->get('schedule_diary')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
$this->db->where('start >', $currentDate)->get('schedule_diary')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, raw query

```
select * from schedule_diary group by group_identify_id having start > CURDATE()
```

for codeigniter you can use

```
$this->db->table('schedule_diary')->group_by('group_identify_id')->having('start', $currentDate);
```